# How to assign productIds to websites?

Tags: magento2, multi-website

Maganto1.x have code below code  to assign multiple productIds to multiple websites.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds)
```

In magento2, How do get same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply set multiple product id to website using magento 2 as below way, Set `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\WebsiteFactory` to your construct and set productids.

```
protected $_productWebsiteFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\WebsiteFactory $productWebsiteFactory

) {
    $this->_productWebsiteFactory = $productWebsiteFactory;
}
```

Use inside function like below,

```
$this->_productWebsiteFactory->create()->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds);
```

Comment: nice answer Rakesh +1